# law of large numbers in information theory

Tags: probability-theory

$\{X_j\}$ is a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables. Let $P\{ X_1=k \} = p_k, 1\le k \le l$, $\sum_{k=1}^l p_k=1$. Let $N(n,\omega)$ be the number of values of $j$, $1\le j \le n$, for which $X_j=k$ and $\prod(n,\omega)=\prod_{k=1}^l p_k^{N(n,\omega)}$. Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}log\prod(n,\omega)$exists a.e.

This is an exercise from Kai Lai Chung's $A\ Course\ in\  Probability\ Theory$, applications of law of large numbers, but I even cannot see the form of $\frac{1}{n}\sum_j^n$. I only work out that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^l log(p_k^{N(n,\omega)})$.

Comment: Hint: $\log(xy)=\log(x)+\log(y)$.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou But the number the summands are fixed$l$ not $n$, how to change to that form?